# How to import all requirements from a specific path in qc through vba?

Tags: vba, ota, hp-quality-center

I want to import all the requirements with their `requirement number` and `requirement ID` from a specific path in QC. I am unable to find the exact OTA code. Can someone show me how to use VBA to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using VBA code, use 'Addins for Excel' in QC. That's much better.

You shall first take an export of one of a requirment and save the excel file. And, edit it to add your requiremnets and import it. Done.

This is my personal experience and I've been using QC from last three years.

Comment: Hi I would like to import from QC to Excel. I guess your suggesting the vice versa. Kindly correct me if I’m wrong. Exporting from QC to excel is a part of my code and not my only task.